# How to factorise an expression which doesn't factorise over the integers?

Tags: factoring

How can I factorise this expression:

$$x^2+58x+100$$

I got an answer and I don't know if it's correct:

$(x+\surd 741 -2a)(x-\surd 741 -2a)$.

Comment: What is $a{}{}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that $2a$ should be $29$ and the sign should be positive (if the roots of the equation are $a,b$ the factorisation is $(x-a)(x-b)$)

Check sum of negatives of roots $(29+\sqrt {741})+(29-\sqrt {741})=58$

Check product of roots $(29+\sqrt {741})(29-\sqrt {741})=29^2-741=100$

Answer (score 0):

Is "$2a$" a typo? If not,it should be $(x+29-\sqrt{741})(x+29+\sqrt{741})$.

Using completing square method,

\begin{align}
x^2+58x+100&=(x+29)^2-29^2+100\\&=(x+29)^2-741\\&=(x+29-\sqrt{741})(x+29+\sqrt{741})
\end{align}

If yes and you meant $-29$, you still get it wrong as it should be$+29.$

Comment: Fixed thx @mathlove.